# Directive angularjs only input number in a range 1 to 10, jquery to directive angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, types, limit

I am new in the world of angularjs, I need to enter only numbers from 1 to 10 in an input of type number. without using the min and max properties of HTML5

I found an example in Jquery, could you please help me to convert it into an angularjs directive, with its respective parameters that is:

```
<input type = "number" directive-range = "1,10">
```

The example I found in Jquery is the following. the example in jquery works without the min and max properties of html5 and is what I need:

```
<input type = "number" value = "1" min = "1" max = "10">
<p style = "display: none"> Accepting Only values ​​1-10 </ p>

var t = false

$ ('input'). focus (function () {
    var $ this = $ (this)
    
    t = setInterval (

    function () {
        if (($ this.val () <1 || $ this.val ()> 10) && $ this.val (). length! = 0) {
            if ($ this.val () <1) {
                $ this.val (1)
            }

            if ($ this.val ()> 10) {
                $ this.val (10)
            }
            $ ('p'). fadeIn (1000, function () {
                $ (this) .fadeOut (500)
            })
        }
    }, fifty)
})

$ ('input'). blur (function () {
    if (t! = false) {
        window.clearInterval (t)
        t = false;
    }
})
```

[Example Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/VJTFm/1/)

I hope you can help me I do not understand much about angularjs directives

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the directive only inputs numbers from 1 to 10 right? have you tried changing the `directive-limit` or the `min` and `max` values?

Comment: I want to convert the jquery example to an angularjs directive. parameterized for the use of limits.
without using the min and max properties of HTML5

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native HTML5 properties for [input of type number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number): [min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-min) and [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-max).

Behind scenes AngularJS will use the [min-length](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength) and [max-length](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength) directives.

As long as you can use these, I strongly recommend you to do so instead of creating a new directive.

Comment: thank you for your answer but in my case I should not use the min and max properties of HTML5

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing whether you need a Angular Directive which accepts only Numbers!! If yes, please see code below which accepts only Numbers in a TextBox.

```
ngControlMod.directive('numbersOnly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                if (text) {
                    var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9-]/g, '');
                    if (transformedInput !== text) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                    return transformedInput;
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

and in your HTML5 code,

```
<input type="text" numbers-only name="Count" />
```

You can also look here the working code jsfiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/sudi065/5f2c03hj/)

Comment: if I need to only accept number in a range, in my case from 1 to 10. In case you enter a number less than 0 or greater than 10, you should behave like the example of jquery

my input has to be type number since I need to use the pick

Comment: Brilliant. I added this so that you couldn't put minuses in the middle, eg **1-4** : `.replace(/(.+)-/, '$1')`